# Scraping table (several pages) to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to transfer the data of a long table *(24 pages)* to a Pandas Dataframe, but facing some issues with *(i think)* the for-loop code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

base_url = 'https://scrapethissite.com/pages/forms/?page_num={}'
res = requests.get(base_url.format('1'))
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')

table = soup.select('table.table')[0]
columns = table.find('tr').find_all('th')
columns_names = [str(c.get_text()).strip() for c in columns]
table_rows = table.find_all('tr', class_='team')

l = []
for n in range(1, 25):
    scrape_url = base_url.format(n)
    res = requests.get(scrape_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
    for tr in table_rows:
        td = tr.find_all('td')
        row = [str(tr.get_text()).strip() for tr in td]
        l.append(row)

df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=columns_names)
```

The Dataframe comes out as a repetition of the first page only, rather than a copy of all the data in the table.

Comment: `table_rows` is set outside the for loop, and so doesn't change inside the loop. Is this your issue?

Comment: It didn't work on its own, but @Corralien 's solution worked. Thank you.

Comment: FYI pandas [`read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) allows to load html tables directly from urls.

Comment: @RJAdriaansen I'll make sure to try it out, but the purpose of this code I'm trying was to practice web scraping as a concept, I just added the Pandas part to make it harder. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @mxbi.

Try it:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

base_url = 'https://scrapethissite.com/pages/forms/?page_num={}'

l = []
for n in range(1, 25):
    scrape_url = base_url.format(n)
    res = requests.get(scrape_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')

    table = soup.select('table.table')[0]
    columns = table.find('tr').find_all('th')
    columns_names = [str(c.get_text()).strip() for c in columns]
    table_rows = table.find_all('tr', class_='team')

    for tr in table_rows:
        td = tr.find_all('td')
        row = [str(tr.get_text()).strip() for tr in td]
        l.append(row)

df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=columns_names)
```

Comment: Looks good, I tried @mxbi 's suggestion at first but it didn't work, but this certainly did. Can you explain to me what was I doing wrong by assigning the variables before the for-loop? I'm a beginner and this would be very helpful to me, Thank you.

Comment: The code outside of a loop is executed only once while you need to update some parts at each iteration. In your case, you need to update `table`, `columns`, `columns_names`, `table_rows` at each time you get a new page.

Answer (score 0):

requests is needed because the server wants an user-agent header and pandas read_html doesn't allow for that. As you still want to use pandas to generate the dataframe you could gain some efficiency through using multiprocessing to handle the requests, and within an user defined function extract the table of interest and pass as string to read_html. You will get a list of dataframes which can be combined with pandas concat.

Note: This can't be run from within Jupyter as will block.

```
import pandas as pd
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

def get_table(url:str)-> pd.DataFrame:
    soup = bs(requests.get(url).text, 'lxml')
    df = pd.read_html(str(soup.select_one('.table')))[0]
    df['page_num'] = url.split("=")[-1]
    return df

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    urls = [f'https://scrapethissite.com/pages/forms/?page_num={i}' for i in range(1, 25)]

    with Pool(cpu_count()-1) as p:
        results = p.map(get_table, urls)

    final = pd.concat(results)
    print(final)
    # final.to_csv('data.csv', index = False, encoding = 'utf-8-sig')
```